# Plotting a function of three variables in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot the contour lines for this function, however I cannot find any useful way to do it.

The potential function is :
`V(x,y,z) = cos(10x) + cos(10y) + cos(10z) + 2*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`

I unsuccessfully attempted something like:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot.contour

def V(x,y,z):
    return numpy.cos(10*x) + numpy.cos(10*y) + numpy.cos(10*z) + 2*(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)

X, Y, Z = numpy.mgrid[-1:1:100j, -1:1:100j, -1:1:100j]
```

But then, I don't know how to do the next step to plot it?

```
matplotlib.pyplot.contour(X,Y,Z,V)
```

Comment: I think that plotting four-dimensional data (three arguments and the potential) in 3D space isn't going to work. Fundamentally. Is there no way to reduce the dimensionality of the problem, e.g. using the Buckingham-Pi theorem, i.e. non-dimensionalising some variables? If not and the `X,Y,Z` are just mock arguments not Cartesian components, you'll probably have to resort to multiple series (mentioned by dermen), video, scatter plots with varying sizes, colour-coding, or projecting onto `X,Y,Z`, so plotting `V(X,Y)`, `V(Y,Z)` and `V(X,Z)` separately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An error will arise when you try to pass `contour` three-dimensional arrays, as it expects two-dimensional arrays.

With this in mind, try:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

def V(x,y,z):
     return np.cos(10*x) + np.cos(10*y) + np.cos(10*z) + 2*(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)

X,Y = np.mgrid[-1:1:100j, -1:1:100j]
Z_vals = [ -0.5, 0, 0.9 ]
num_subplots = len( Z_vals)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
for i,z in enumerate( Z_vals):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1 , num_subplots , i+1, projection='3d')
    ax.contour(X, Y, V(X,Y,z), cmap=cm.gnuplot)
    ax.set_title('z = %.2f'%z, fontsize=30)
fig.savefig('contours.png', facecolor='grey', edgecolor='none')
```

[image]

Instead, use `ax.contourf(...)` to show the surfaces, which looks nicer in my opinion.

[image]

There is no direct way to visualize a function of 3 variables, as it is an object (surface) which lives in 4 dimensions. One must play with slices of the function to see what's going on. By a slice, I mean a projection of the function onto a lower dimensional space. A slice is achieved by setting one or more of the function variables as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what the OP needed, but I think a possible solution might be this one:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def compute_torus(precision, c, a):
    U = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, precision)
    V = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, precision)
    U, V = np.meshgrid(U, V)
    X = (c+a*np.cos(V))*np.cos(U)
    Y = (c+a*np.cos(V))*np.sin(U)
    Z = a*np.sin(V)
    return X, Y, Z

x, y, z = compute_torus(100, 2, 1)

fig = plt.figure()

color_dimension = z  # Here goes the potential
minn, maxx = color_dimension.min(), color_dimension.max()
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(minn, maxx)
m = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='jet')
m.set_array([])
fcolors = m.to_rgba(color_dimension)

# plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x,y,z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=fcolors, vmin=minn, vmax=maxx, shade=False)
```

Setting color_dimension to the values of the potential function, using this code can be plotted over a torus. In general, it can be plotted over any 3D shape of (x,y,z), but of course if the 3D space is fully filled with points everywhere, it's unlikely the image will be clear.

Comment: `ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')` is deprecated. use `ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')`