# Plot and function with three variables in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

An equation which is represent as below

```
sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)+cos(x)*sin(y)*cos(z)=0
```

I know the code to plot function for z=f(x,y) using matplotlib but to plot above function I don’t know the code, but I tried MATLAB MuPad code which is as follows

```
Plot(sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)+cos(x)*sin(y)*cos(z),#3d)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting a function of three variables in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492313/plotting-a-function-of-three-variables-in-python)

Comment: You can try `mplot3d`. https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-toolkits-mplot3d-py

Comment: All the above resources (1) takes different values of z to give different plots but my aim is to mimic the function in mupad to plot an expression equating to 0. Resource (2) has all the function where z is the function of two other variables but in my code z is also an independent variable so function in that library fails

Comment: Do you have any domain for the values of x, y, z?

Answer (score 1):

This will be much easier if you can isolate `z`. Your equation is the same as `sin(z)/cos(z) = -cos(x)*sin(y)/(sin(x)*sin(y))` so `z = atan(-cos(x)*sin(y)/(sin(x)*sin(y)))`.

Comment: If you simplify further, you can cancel `sin(y)` in numerator and denominator, but I don't think its proper.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that. So really the equation is `z = atan(-1/tan(x))` or `y = n*pi` (for integer `n`). These two can be plotted separately on top of each other using most standard 3d plotting toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't mistake me, but I think your given equation to plot can be reduced to a simple 2D plot.

```
sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)+cos(x)*sin(y)*cos(z) = 0
sin(y)[sin(x)*sin(z)+cos(x)*cos(z)] = 0
sin(y)*cos(x-z) = 0
Hence sin(y) = 0 or cos(x-z)=0
Hence y = n*pi (1) or x-z=(2*n + 1)pi/2
Implies, x = z + (2*n + 1)pi/2 (2)
```

For (1), it will be a straight line (the plot of y vs n) and in second case, you will get parallel lines which cuts x-axis at (2*n + 1)pi/2 and distance between two parallel lines would be pi. (Assuming you keep n constant).

Assuming, your `y` can't be zero, you could simplify the plot to a 2D plot with just `x` and `z`.

And answering your original question, you need to use `mplot3d` to plot 3D plots. But as with any graphing tool, you need values or points of `x`, `y`, `z`. (You can compute the possible points by programming). Then you feed those points to the plot, like below.

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
xs = [] # X values
ys = [] # Y values
zs = [] # Z values
ax.plot3D(xs, ys, zs)
plt.show()
```

Comment: y = 0 or x - z = pi/2 are only some of the solutions. The real answers should be periodic, like `y = n*pi` or `x - z = n*pi - pi/2` for integer `n`.